# Call javascript on checkbox onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I just want my function to be called when I click the checkbox. Replacing the function call with `alert()` works, am I referencing my function incorrectly?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function select(a){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=""+a;
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="select(1)">

<div id="myDiv">hi</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the function name [e.g. selectFun]. `select` seems to be reserved keyword

Answer (score 3):

This puzzled me as it looked ok to me too, So ran through the usual tests, eventually tried changing the function name and that worked fine.

Comment: Actually is does answer the question, it's just a really badly written answer from 4 years ago, no doubt when I was in a rush. Note "Tried changing the function name and that worked fine", also note the accepted answer above which involved changing the function name. In all probability d the accepted answer was posted whilst I was writing/testing things out.